# Moving mouse over WinForm that opens second form causes second to lose focus?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having a strange error.  I have a WinForms app that, when an object in a TreeListView is clicked, opens a "viewer" in a second form.  The viewer was originally a second app we wrote that I converted to a DLL and embedded into my program.

Anyway, when viewed on the same monitor, the viewer shows over top of the original form.  When the mouse is moved over the original opener (not click on), the new form drops behind it and cannot retain focus.

Some bit of code that is used to show the form:

```
 if (showImg != null)
      showImg.Close();

showImg = new frmMain(document, fileType.Mime == "application/pdf");
this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => showImg.Show()));
```

I'm not sure what is triggering the main to get back focus.

Answer (score 0):

When you show the second window you need to supply the Owner window in the first parameter

```
myAwesomeWindow.ShowDialog(this); // where "this" is your calling Owner view/form
myAwesomeWindow.Show(this);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't being shown modal.  It's more of a viewer than an editor.  Just to try it out I did what you suggested and it still drops behind the main screen.

Comment: @SpaceCowboy74 So you passed in the calling window? sorry my answer was a worded a little wrong with the word model

Comment: yes.  Made the call `this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => showImg.Show(this)))` and it still happened.

Comment: @SpaceCowboy74 does this happen with a regular non modal dialog, i think there might be more to the picture here, this shouldnt really happen, i mean making a window active and bringing it to the front most, shouldnt really happen unless its made to